# Monitor c3p0 (with hibernate and Tomcat) with JConsole

Tags: hibernate, tomcat, jmx, c3p0, jconsole

The Web App is a Struts application (no spring) using c3p0 with Hibernate and it's in Tomcat 6. Both Hibernate and c3p0 jars are in the {WEB_APP}/WEB-INF/lib folder.

In Tomcat the jmx remote is enabled:
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8888
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false

When I use jconsole connecting to it, I do not see the c3p0 MBean in the tab.

Is there any configuration I need to do in Tomcat or the web app?

Thanks!

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue? We are facing the same problem here.

Answer (score 2):

When you are not using Spring or JBoss then things are a little more hands on when it comes to JMX monitoring of Hibernate.

You need to do the following:

- In your Hibernate Configuration add:

  ```
  <property name="hibernate.generate_statistics">true</property>
  ```
- Then in a startup segment of your app you need to register the MBeans with the MBean server:

  `MBeanServer mbeanServer = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
  ObjectName objectName = new ObjectName("org.hibernate:type=statistics");
  StatisticsService mBean = new StatisticsService();
  mBean.setStatisticsEnabled(true);
  mBean.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
  mbeanServer.registerMBean(mBean, objectName);`